# How to Set Up Continuous Deployment for an Umbraco Project in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: azure, umbraco, umbraco7, azure-devops, umbraco6

So I have been in experimenting and researching mode for the past 2 weeks, trying to setup a Umbraco 6 Web App via Nuget that can be checked into Visual Studio Team Services, and be deployed on check in (Azure Continuous Deployment via TFS).

I know this is a common discussion among the Umbraco community, which is frankly why I ask, because I can't find any clear delineation on how it ***should*** be done.

My primary questions:

- What folders should/shouldn't be included in my Visual Studio Project?
- What folders should/shouldn't be included in VSO [or any source control]?
- What folders should/shouldn't be included in deployment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include all the additional Umbraco files and folders that installed via Nuget.

For Umbraco 6, they are:

- App_Browsers
- install
- umbraco
- umbraco_client
- config\splashes
- Global.asax

You can refer to this article for some reference: [How to deploy Umbraco 7 to an Azure Website using Visual Studio Online](http://maffrigby.com/how-to-deploy-umbraco-7-to-an-azure-website-using-visual-studio-online/).

Comment: Too bad your answer is mostly a link answer... which.. of course... is now broken. Would be awesome to get this info into StackOverflow. Adding the folders was easy, but how to setup VSTS to actually check your VSTS repo for changes, take the necessary files and deloy them to an Azure AppService.. where are all of those steps? How exactly do I setup the VSTS Build and Release?

Comment: Also, an Umbraco 7 guide would be most beneficial.